# Using queryLocator in the REST API /services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest

Tags: rest-api, parameters

I am doing a report for my Jobs and I need to return a specific Job information using the REST API /services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest.

When I am using the REST API, it is limited to 1000 records. I could get the nextRecordsUrl and get more records. However, I would like to avoid a bunch of API callouts.

In this way, I would like to use the **queryLocator** as  parameter, but I am not finding any example.

Also, Salesforce documentation is very poor in this part and I found only this info:

```
Use queryLocator with a locator value to get a specific set of job results. Get All Jobs returns up to 1000 result rows per request, along with a nextRecordsUrl value that contains the locator value used to get the next set of results.
```

So, is it possible to filter this REST API? And how? Or is **queryLocator** used only to return the next rows?

[Bulk API - Get All Jobs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_all_jobs.htm)

Comment: I think `nextRecordsUrl`  is the querryLocator, You have to call that endpoint to get next set of records. I cant think of a way via which you will be able to save API calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a best explanation what is the **queryLocator**

> A query locator represents a server-side cursor for a query. Typically
>   a query locator is returned when not all the records requested in a
>   query fit into the returned data set. This way a queryMore() can be
>   issued with the provided query locator to get additional rows.

It means that it is not used to filter, but to return the next query set of values.

Source: ['Invalid Query Locator' error](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004410&language=en_US)